# CSS Issue - Columns Resize Automatically When Browser Window Shrinks/Enlarges

Tags: css, width, margin, center, multiple-columns

Hopefully this will be an easy question to answer - it is puzzling me tremendously:

I have designed my page with Pinterest in mind - separating the main content into columns.  I have specified the columns as follows:

```
#Content {
width: auto;
margin: 0px auto;

-moz-column-count:auto;
-webkit-column-count:auto;
column-count:auto;

-moz-column-gap: 20px;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
column-gap: 20px;

-moz-column-width: 294px;
-webkit-column-width: 294px;
column-width: 294px;
}

#Body {
width: 100%;
}
```

When resizing the browser, the number of columns increases and decreases to fit the screen.   However, both the left and right columns are flat against the side of the screen - the gaps between the columns remains steady at 20px - but the width of each column increases to fill the remaining gaps.

Is there a way that I can get it like Pinterest - where the gaps between the columns remains fixed and the column width remains fixed - while the margin on the left and right of the content varies?

Comment: I am assuming you want to achieve this without setting a fixed width on #content? You want it responsive, right?

Comment: Keep in mind that Pinterest and most other designs of this type don't use tables. Please stay away from them unless you are using them to display a dataset.

Comment: Exactly - to be able to fill the screen regardless of the size of monitor.

Comment: Pinterest uses JS to display its content.  Are you willing to use JS for this problem?

Comment: For simplicity I was trying to stay away from javascript - it currently functions perfectly as a table now - only the width of the columns not remaining fixed is my issue

Comment: Pinterest uses something like jQuery Masonry to make rows of unequal height. If you don't need that, then you're fine to stay away and just use something like floating or inline divs.

Comment: Exactly - the columns are of unequal height and display the content just fine - the only problem I'm having the maintaining the width of each of the columns.  Could it be a priority issue? The priority of the margin of the the content outweighs the priority of the width of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? Resize the brower, to see the 3 different sizes.

[**Coding here..**](http://jsfiddle.net/KxCss/1/)

[**Full screen example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KxCss/1/embedded/result/)

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col {
        width:18%;
        float:left;
        margin:0px 1%;
    }
    img {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        margin-top:6%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col {
        width:30%;
        float:left;
        margin:0px 1%;
    }
    img {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        margin-top:6%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {
        width:45%;
        float:left;
        margin:0px 1%;
    }
    img {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        margin-top:6%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the issue I'm having - the boxes increase/decrease in size with the changing browser window while the margins remain constant.

Comment: I only want the "boxes" to remain constant regardless of monitor size while the margins separating them also remain constant and the margins on the very left and very right are dynamic

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted responsive columns? What exactly is it that you are aiming for?

Comment: Wait - when changing your .col width from a % to a px amount - the "boxes" remain constant. That is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: When resizing the browser the margins in between also remain constant - I can play around with this now and hopefully get something to click!  Thank you Josh!